# Batch file to detect if local printer is installed and to do stuff if it isn't

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delimiter, token

I'm creating a batch file to detect if a local printer has been installed and if it hasn't other code will run.

```
For /F "Tokens=1 delims=" %%I In ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices" ^|find /I "WPL"') Do If "%%I"=="Printer WPL-606" Goto :EOF
REM Otherwise Do Stuff
```

The result I'm getting when I run this is:

> C:\Documents and Settings\kalamane>If "    Printer
>   WPL-606   REG_SZ  winspool,Ne07:" == "Printer WPL-606" Goto :EOF
>
> C:\Documents and Settings\kalamane>REM Otherwise Do Stuff

Clearly the rest of the line from that registry entry is included in the comparison, so it fails.

I'm pretty new to scripting and I think what I'm getting wrong is the tokens and delimiters.  Here's the line from the registry when only a reg query is used:

```
Printer WPL-606     REG_SZ  winspool,Ne07:
```

Can someone explain how I can go about getting this to pick out the correct part of the registry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Querying the registry, and with the tokens/delims you are using, you are grabbing the entire line output. You need to set spaces as your delims and grab the first 2 tokens. You would want the following:

```
For /F "Tokens=1,2 delims= " %%I In ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices" ^|find /I "WPL"') Do (
  If "%%I %%J"=="Printer WPL-606" (
     GOTO:EOF
  ) ELSE (
     REM Otherwise Do Stuff
  )
)
```

Or you can use `PRNMNGR`. It's a VBS script localized in .\windows\system32\prnmngr.vbs   that helps you to manage printers (including listing them). So it would go like this:

```
cscript "C:\WINDOWS\system32\prnmngr.vbs" -l -s \\localhost | FIND /I "WPL-606"
IF [%errorlevel%] == [0] (
  GOTO:EOF
) ELSE (
  REM Otherwise Do Stuff
)
```

You can check out the command in CMD with `PRNMNGR /?`

Answer (score 2):

While Mechaflash's answer is great (Especially the second part about prnmngr.vbs), running the `PRNMNGR` takes up to ten seconds to get back results.

Using Microsoft's [Devcon](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q311272) returns results nearly instantly.
Here's the code modified to use it:

```
For /F "Tokens=1,2 delims=\" %%I In ('devcon.exe findall *WPL-606*') Do (
  If "%%J"=="PRINTERWPL-606" (
     GOTO:EOF
  ) ELSE (
     REM Otherwise Do Stuff
  )
)
```

I'm including this answer for completeness because it solves my problem and will help future visitors searching for such a batch file.  I'm accepting Mechaflash's answer because it answers my actual question.

Comment: My answer will work in an enterprise environment where dependencies may not be allowed =D

Answer (score 0):

More generalized answer checking for a network printer taking the server and printer as arguments and installing if needed.

printer_check.cmd:

```
@ECHO OFF
@CLS

SET SERVER=%~1
SET SHARE=%~2
   
For /F "Tokens=* delims=\" %%I In ('reg query "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Devices" ^| find /I "\\%SERVER%\%SHARE%"') Do (
IF [%errorlevel%] == [0] (
  ECHO Printer \\%SERVER%\%SHARE% Installed
  GOTO:EOF
) ELSE (
  ECHO Printer \\%SERVER%\%SHARE% NOT Installed
  GOTO:AddPrinter
)
)

:AddPrinter
ECHO Installing Printer \\%SERVER%\%SHARE%
set PRINTUI=rundll32 printui.dll PrintUIEntry /q /in /ga /n
%PRINTUI% "\\%SERVER%\%SHARE%"

:EOF
```

Test:

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS

set SERVER=
set SHARE=

CALL "printer_check.cmd" %SERVER% %SHARE%

PAUSE
```